# Finding components of a vector field in spherical coordinates using the inverse metric

Tags: tensors, spherical-coordinates

In [The Poor Man's Introduction to Tensors](https://justincfeng.github.io/Tensors_Poor_Man.pdf), exercise X.3:

In Cartesian coordinates, the simplest nonvanishing vector field you can write down is the constant vector field:
$$
v^1 = 1 \\
v^2 = 0 \\
v^3 = 0 \\
$$

Lower the indices to get the components of the dual vector $v_i$. Obtain the components $v_\alpha$ for the dual vector field in spherical coordinates, and use the components of the inverse metric $g^{\alpha \beta}$ (see exercise **X.2**) to obtain the components for the vector field $v^\alpha$ in spherical coordinates. Finally, obtain the components for the vector in the unit-vector basis: $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$, $\hat{\phi}$.

I understand how to get the components of the dual vector field, and how to obtain the components for the vector in the unit-vector basis once I know the components in the partial derivative basis. What I don't know is how to get the components in spherical coordinates using using the inverse metric $g^{\alpha \beta}$.

Answer (score 1):

The lowering of components is easy, since the metric tensor for Cartesian coordinates is the identity, so we have $v_1=1$ and $v_2=v_3=0$. The components of this dual vector in spherical coordinates are computed using the transformation law of

$$\bar{v}_\alpha=\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial\bar{x}^\alpha}v_\beta$$

where $x^\alpha$ are the Cartesian coordinates and $\bar{x}^\alpha$ are the spherical coordinates. Since we know $v_\beta$ for each $\beta$, we have

$$\bar{v}_\alpha=\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial\bar{x}^\alpha}$$

In these coordinates,

$$v_r=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r},\;\;v_\theta=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta},\;\;v_\phi=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}$$

Under the formula

$$x=r\cos\phi\sin\theta $$

we have

$$v_r=\cos\phi\sin\theta,\;\;v_\theta=r\cos\phi\cos\theta,\;\;v_\phi=-r\sin\phi\sin\theta$$

To raise the indices, we use the inverse metric tensor. The metric tensor for spherical coordinates is

$$g_{\alpha\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

For $(r,\theta,\phi)$. We can raise the index by

$$\bar{v}^\alpha=g^{\alpha\beta}\bar{v}_\beta$$

but since $g$ is diagonal, we have

$$\bar{v}^\alpha=g^{\alpha\alpha}\bar{v}_{\alpha}$$

and there is no sum being taken. Since the matrix is diagonal the inverse of the matrix is just the reciprocal of the terms, so we have

$$\bar{v}^\alpha=\frac{1}{g_{\alpha\alpha}}\bar{v}_\alpha$$

As such,

$$\bar{v}^r=\cos\phi\sin\theta,\;\;\bar{v}^\theta=\frac{\cos\phi\cos\theta}{r},\;\;\bar{v}^\phi=-\frac{\sin\phi}{r\sin\theta}$$

The shorter way of getting this by using the transformation law

$$\bar{v}^\alpha=\frac{\partial\bar{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}v^\beta$$

but it requires that we know the derivative of the spherical coordinates with respect to the Cartesian coordinates and then transform these back to spherical coordinates.